# Label in Custom UITableView cell not allocated memory in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios6, uilabel

I have made a custom `UITableViewCell` which has elements like label and a `segmentcontrol` But when i try to access the elements in the `cellforrowatindexpath` the elements are not allocated any memory . the cell instance has been allocated memory . i have checked the xib and connected the outlets.
Here is the code in the `cellforrowatindexpath`-

```
SegmentCell *cell;
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SegmentCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SegmentCell"];
[tableView registerClass:[SegmentCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SegmentCell"];
cell = (SegmentCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SegmentCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.title.text=@"Hell*emphasized text*o";
return cell;
```

The title is the label which shows nil in print description

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell’s `title` is a deprecated property of type NSString, not UILabel. Use the `titleLabel` property instead.

`cell.titleLabel.text = @"whatever";`

Comment: title is the name of the label i have created. sorry should have made it clear.
is there a conflict because of the name?

Answer (score 0):

Since `title` is a property of your custom class *SegmentCell*, you are responsible to allocate an instance of UILabel and assign it to title. If it is included in your Nib file, be sure it is bound to the class property.